# How to get the system time zone in MySQL with the proper encoding?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the configured MySQL system time zone using the query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'system_time_zone'
```

This is on Windows. My system configured time zone is supposed to be `Est (Heure d'Été)` which is the french for "East (Summer time)".

```
import MySQLdb

con = MySQLdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'Test', 'pwd', 'mydb')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'system_time_zone'")
```

> -> show warning: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\x92\xE9t\xE9)' for column
>   'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 478

However, for some reason, the request only gives back `Est (Heure d` which I assuming is because of some encoding or configuration error. I can't figure out why this happens nor how to fix it.

Do you have any clue ? I'm using MySQL server 5.7 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: It absolutely has something to do with `'`, where are you running this query?

Comment: @HankyPanky I'm not sure it has to do with the quote. I tried both from my Python code and from MySQL workbench. The latter does not show any warning but just displays the truncated value.